# How to make the Text item always display fractional parts of numbers?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a `Text` item that display a `real` number:

```
Text { id: txt; ... }

...

txt.text: Math.round(sensor.value*10)/10

...
```

But if `sensor.value` is the integer number, it's displayed without a fractional part (`35` instead `35.0`). How to explicitly force `txt` always display a fractional part of number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var num = 5.11;
num.toFixed(1);
```

It will round up to 1 place of decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use toPrecision method to specify the number of decimals you want to show. The method will return a string with the number formatted in the desired format

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: It works, but in this case numbers that < 1 display like: `0.10` instead of `0.1`